# Is regex match guaranteed to always only look out for the last pattern? C++

Tags: c++, regex

Assume I have a string like this:

```
"a-b-c-d"
```

*n = 4 sequences seperated by `"-"`*.

Now I want to receive the first n - 1 sequences (`"a-b-c"`) and the last sequence - (`"d"`).

I can achieve this with the following code:

```
std::string string{ "a-b-c-d" };

std::regex reg{ "^(.*)-(.*)$" };

std::smatch match;
std::regex_match(string, match, reg);

std::cout << match.str(1) << '\n';
std::cout << match.str(2) << '\n';
```

producing the excpected output:

```
a-b-c
d
```

---

However, following the pure logical grammar of this regex (`"^(.*)-(.*)$"`)

```
a
b-c-d
```

or

```
a-b
c-d
```

could also be valid matches of the string. Afterall `(.*)` *could* be interpreted differently here and the first `(.*)` could decide to stop at the first character sequence or the second etc.

So my question: is `std::smatch` guaranteed to behave this way? Does `std::smatch` always explicitly look for the last patterns when giving the option to capture with `(.*)`? Is there a way to tell `std::smatch` to look for the first occurrence rather than the last?

Comment: You want to read about "greedy" and "lazy" regex quantifiers.

Comment: @n.m. that looks promising, thank you.

Comment: BTW you don't need anchors like `$` and `^` when using `regex_match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is greedy. So the first `(.*)` matches as much as it can while the second `(.*)` still has something left to match. There is only one correct match, and it is the one you want.

If you want the first group to be matched non-greedily, add a `?` after the `*`:

```
^(.*?)-(.*)$
```

For your example input `a-b-c-d` this leaves you with `a` in the first capture group and `b-c-d` in the second.

Comment: So is `"^(.*)-(.*)$"` afterall the same as  `"^(.*)-(.*?)$"` ?

Comment: The results are the same. The matching mechanism is not, unless optimization kicks in to optimize `(.*?)` to `(.*)`in this special case.